# In Out of Oz who visits Glinda in prison?

Tags: wicked, gregory-maguire

I've just finished the last book in Gregory Maguire's Wicked series, Out of Oz. There are all sorts of plot holes and unresolved threads in the book, some of which are obviously deliberate. In particular, in the penultimate chapter Glinda is in prison and receives a visitor. The chapter ends:

> Her glasses had broken a year ago. She didn’t need them anymore, not really. She knew who was turning the door handle of her cell. She called her name sleepily, and added, “You wicked thing. You’ve taken your own sweet time, of course.”

My question is: who is the visitor?

I can think of two possibilities:

1. the visitor could be a revived Elphaba. We've already had a hint that Elphaba may be alive when Nanny claims to have seen Elphaba at Kiamo Ko, and *you wicked thing* suggests it's Elphaba.
2. the visitor could actually be a vision of impending death. We know Nanny is old and frail and it's implied that Glinda is no longer in the best of health. I wonder if the implication is that they're about to join Elphaba in death (now I put this in writing it seems a bit improbable :-)

I realise there's no answer to this unless someone knows of comments by Maguire about the subject, but I ask on the off chance that someone hereabouts knows of such comments. Both of the possibilities seem rather arbitrary in that they're unrelated to the plot of the book and make no special contribution to it.